# Database schema for efficient attendance management system

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, architecture, schema

I am developing an attendance system for school which will cater to both employees as well as students.

The current db schema is

`attendance` table

```
id - primary key for this table
daydate  int(11) - stores timestamp of current day
timing_in varchar(18) - Start time for institution
timing_out - Closing time for institution
status - Status for the day, can be working day - 1 or holiday - 2
```

Then there are different tables for staff & students, which store the actual attendance values.

For staff, the attendance is stored in `attendance_staff`. The database schema is

```
attendance_id - foreign key, references attendance table
staff_id - id of staff member, references staff master table
time_in - stores in timing of a staff member
time_out - stores out timing of a staff member
status - attendance status - can be one among the list, like present, absent, casual leave, half day, late mark, on duty, maternity leave, medical leave etc
```

For staff, i am storing both present as well as not present entries in the table.

Now attendance for students has to be included with it.

Since status of each day is already stored in `attendance` table, can we store not present values for each student in the student attendance table.

Like, the student attendance table will store only entries for those days who are not present on a particular day.

The schema for `attendance_student` will be

```
attendance_id - references attendance table
student_id - references student table
status - will be leave / absent etc other than present.
```

Will it be efficient to calculate the present days from attendance table using outer join??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an outer join to calculate attendance for students.  You could simply count the records in your attendance table (one time, since it would be the same for all students) and then just select from your student attendance table to get absences.

If you'd prefer to count attendance with an outer join you could.  It is likely to be more than efficient enough if you have an index on your attendance table primary key and on the foreign key from student attendance table to your attendance table.

Comment: Thank you Joel.

Should the Present status be stored in database as well against each student for each day. 

What about I have to get attendance of last year for a particular month of a particular student?

How can it be checked, whether the student was available for attendance at that time or not. Whether he was active / inactive / suspended etc. Because for non active students, attendance will not be available in the system.

Comment: @Ehs4n - If it were me, I would store _present_ explicitly.  I would do this because it would distinguish between students being present and data being missing.  Until attendance is recorded you can't tell whether a student was present or if attendance is "to be determined".  For historical data, if you clean out any of your tables when students leave the school or a new school year starts, then you might consider keeping an additional set of historical archive tables that include the school year as an extra field.  Instead of deleting student who leave, archive them instead.

Comment: Thank you once again for your insights. Will you please throw more light on archive feature. How this can be achieved?

Comment: @Ehs4n - Create a set of tables that are copies of your production tables, but consider adding an extra column for year.  Then instead of having a process that merely deletes data from your production tables at the end of the school year, change that process to first copy the data to the archive tables, setting the extra year column as you go. Then delete the data from the production tables after the archive copy is made.  Not every archive table needs to have the extra year column, only tables that don't already have date embedded in them.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions. :)